# Resize Splits in Vim after NERDTreeToggle

Tags: vim, vi, nerdtree

I am looking for a way to automatically resize my open v-split panes in Vim after I call NERDTreeToggle.

I have NERDTreeToggle being called on the shortcut "ctrl+\" at the moment, and ideally what I want is to call the keyboard shortcut "ctrl+w =" immediately afterwards.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your current mapping:

```
:nnoremap <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

You can just append the window command after it:

```
:nnoremap <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle<CR><C-w>=
```

Alternatively, you can execute this from command-line mode as well, via `:normal!`:

```
:nnoremap <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle<Bar>execute "normal! \<lt>C-w>="<CR>
```

Note that for window commands, there's also a special `:wincmd` to invoke them:

```
:nnoremap <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle<Bar>wincmd =<CR>
```